# Different shortcut file size on Windows XP, Server 2003 and 7

Tags: windows, shortcut

I've created shortcuts programmatically ( `CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellLink, (void**)&ipShellLink);`), as well as with Explorer, but the size was very different.

Does anybody know, what is the difference between a Windows XP, Windows Server 2003 and a Windows 7 shortcut file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows XP shortcuts will naturally not have information added to the shortcut file format in Windows Vista or Windows 7. For example, Windows XP shortcuts will not have the VistaAndAboveIDListDataBlock (described in [section 2.5.11](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd871305%28v=prot.13%29.aspx)). Similarly, Windows Vista shortcuts will not have information added in Windows 7.

Comment: Okay, and what is the difference between a programmatically created and an Explorer-created schortcut?